# ansible read username and password from vault

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault

I have my vault token in profile and trying to read username and password from vault on my local and pass those variable to remote host. tried this below able to read username and password as part of getusername and getpassword but in last block they are not able to read as variable please let me know where i'm doing wrong.

```
- name: wait for native_transport_port
  wait_for:
    host="{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    port="9042"
    state=started
    timeout=300

- name: getusername
  gather_facts: no
  become_user: pc_user
  tasks:
  shell: source ~/.profile ;vault_username=`vault read --field=adm path`
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- name: getpassword
  gather_facts: no
  become_user: pc_user
  tasks:
  shell: source ~/.profile ;vault_p=`vault read --field=adm_p path`
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- name:  create keyspace
  command: cqlsh  -u $vault_username -p $vault_p -f filname"
  become_user: ec2-user
```

Comment: the "blocks" `getusername` and `getpassword` appear to be plays, and not just tasks - part of another play as `wait for native_transport_port` and `create keyspace` are. is this intentional, or mistake? this snippet you provided is not the code you are running. it would help if you added the actual code you are using to spot the issues.

Comment: it was intentional. my main concern is  values I'm able to get in gettusername and getpassword vault_username and vault_p . iam not able to pass them in create keyspace while using $vault_username and $vault_p . what is the way to get those variables value passed in keyspace

Comment: i got the error [Bad credentials] message=\"Provided username $vault_username and/or password are incorrect\"',)})"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Comment: you need to change the shell tasks to "echo the string in their output, and use the `register` clause to hold it to a variable in ansible. i will give an example as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as briefly explained in the comment, you need to make the shell tasks return the username and password as output, so that ansible can capture it. please see below the 3 tasks from your snippet modified to do that:

```
- name: getusername
  gather_facts: no
  become_user: pc_user
  tasks:
  shell: source ~/.profile ;vault read --field=adm path
  register: vault_username
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- name: getpassword
  gather_facts: no
  become_user: pc_user
  tasks:
  shell: source ~/.profile ;vault read --field=adm_p path
  register: vault_password
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- name:  create keyspace
  command: "cqlsh  -u {{ vault_username.stdout }} -p  {{ vault_password.stdout }} -f filname"
  become_user: ec2-user
```

these assume that the two shell commands:

```
source ~/.profile ;vault read --field=adm path
source ~/.profile ;vault read --field=adm_p path
```

will return as output only the username/password, and nothing else will be echoed in screen.

**EDIT**

forgot to mention, these ansible variables (vault_username/vault_password) should be in the same play, they are not persistent across plays, not sure they will work the way you have organized your tasks.

hope these help.